# Splitting data into specific, unequal, time ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to split up an excel vendor report with two thousand instances into a pivot table that displays instances that occured before 5PM, between 5-7PM and after 7 PM and I am stumped as how to do this. I tried adding another column with if and and functions to test where the time stamp falls within the given ranges but the only range that only pulls the before 5 PM category for some reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you sort it and manually copy/paste?

Comment: "I tried adding another column with if and and functions"  - always helps to post what you've tried.

Comment: I already deleted my functions and I am going through manually doing it now since there likely isn't a function that will work to split it up into these uneven ranges. But basically they were If(and(a1<"17:00",a1>"4:00, "before 5PM"),if(and(a1>"17:00",a1<"19:00","between 5-7"),if(and(a1>"19:00",a1<"4:00,"after 7"))

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you will need a helper column if you want your pivot table to be able to pull in the data. In the column to the right of your current data block, where I assume the timestamp is in column A, with a time/date format that Excel reads as such, try something like this (starting in the column to the right of your current data block, row 1 and dragged down):

> =if(hour(A1)>19,"After 7PM",if(hour(A1)>17,"After 5PM, Before 7PM","Before 5PM"))

This will first check if it's after 7pm, and if it isn't it then checks if it's after 5pm, and if it isn't we know it's before 5pm.

If this doesn't work show us your data; my guess would be that your 'time stamp' isn't being read as a time stamp by Excel.